# Same sysctl kernel parameters for KVM host and guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kernel, host, sysctl, guest

I need to set up a KVM guest with the following sysctl kernel parameters:

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 87380 16777216

net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 1048576
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 1048576

net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1

net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 300000

net.core.somaxconn = 8192
```

Do I need to set these sysctl kernel parameters on the KVM host or are they independent of each other?

Comment: Let's just apply logic: if you were running a Windows guest from the Linux Host, would there be any relation between settings on guest and host?

Comment: I mean, if we have a guest with significant network traffic, it might be worth setting up the host as well (ie. increase buffer sizes and etc.).

Comment: Will the guest NIC settings (checksum offload and etc.) affect the host in some way? Logically, they shouldn't.